# how to add hamburger description without breaking line?

Tags: html

this is my code for hamburger. i want to add a description for it next to my hamburger

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-click nav2">
   <button onclick="clickme()" class="w3-button w3-white">
   <div class="n2" onclick="myNav2(this)">
   <div class="bar1"></div>
   <div class="bar2"></div>
   <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

i have tried making a row for them and i also tried few combinations with div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-click nav2">
 <p class="description">Hamburger description</p>
 <button onclick="clickme()" class="w3-button w3-white">
  <div class="n2" onclick="myNav2(this)">
     <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
    </button>
    </div>
```